# How to compute the connected spectral form factor for integrable models?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, chaos-theory, integrable-systems

Given a spectrum of $N$ real eigenvalues, $\{E_m \}$ of some Hermitian operator, the connected spectral form factor is defined as follows:
\begin{align}
K_c(t) = \langle \sum_{m,n=1}^N e^{it (E_m-E_n)} \rangle - |\langle \sum_{m=1}^N e^{it (E_m)} \rangle|^2.
\end{align}
For random matrices, the average $\langle .. \rangle$ is over the appropriate ensemble (GOE, GUE, GSE etc). However, for integrable models, I am not sure how to take this average. For example, for a particle in a rectangular box of sides $L_x$ and $L_y$, the energy eigenvalues (in some appropriate units) are generated by the formula
\begin{align}
E(n_x,n_y) = \frac{n_x^2}{L_x^2}+\frac{n_y^2}{L_y^2}.
\end{align}
But if I wanted to compute the connected SFF, do I average of random choices of $L_x$, $L_y$? Is there a guiding principle for what the right thing to do is? Are there papers where a computation of this kind has been done before? The only one I could find was this paper by Jens Marklof [https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~majm/bib/spectral.pdf](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Emajm/bib/spectral.pdf) which is a little hard to follow.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: Is what you want not equation 23 in the Marklof paper you cite?

Comment: Have a look at equation (2) [here](http://www.sternwarte.uni-erlangen.de/~hanke/Uni/5.Sem/NLin/Projekt/SpectralStatistics.pdf)